# External SSD shows too much space used (Samsung T3)

Tags: ssd, external-hard-drive, macos-mojave

I just bought a Samsung T3 SSD (250 Gb) and brought it home. I formatted it to Mac Journaled format and transferred some photos from my other external hard disk.

This transfer was almost 200GB which in my Mac OS Mojave reported only 50Gb free space remaining. This was too much so I removed some video folders which left about 70GB photos on the Samsung.

However, when I connect it to my Mac, it is still shown as if 200Gb were used and only 50Gb free space remaining.

Is there some "cache to flush" or something? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for all replies!

Comment: “Is there some "cache to flush" or something? ” - Did you empty the trash bin?

Comment: Of course (even though this is an EXTERNAL hard drive :) so I guess that should make no difference at all)

Comment: Have you used a tool to visualize your disk usage?